# IBM Speech to Text service call return error

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

I have created IBM Speech to Text service. Then I have performed the trial call using the following IBM instructions:

> Try an API call
>
> Call the POST /v1/recognize method to request a basic transcription of
>   a FLAC audio file with no additional request parameters.
>
> First, download the sample audio file audio-file.flac.
>
> Then, issue the following command to call the service's /v1/recognize
>   method for basic transcription with no parameters. The example uses
>   the Content-Type header to indicate the type of the audio, audio/flac.
>   The example uses the default language model, en-US_BroadbandModel, for
>   transcription. Be sure to modify {path_to_file} to specify the
>   location of the audio-file.flac file.
>
> ```
> curl -X POST \
> -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
> --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" \
> --data-binary @{path_to_file}audio-file.flac \
> "{url}/v1/recognize"
> ```
>
> The service returns the following transcription results:
>
> ```
>  {
>    "results": [
>      {
>        "alternatives": [
>          {
>            "confidence": 0.8691191673278809,
>            "transcript": "several tornadoes touch down as a line of severe thunderstorms swept through colorado on sunday"
>          }
>        ],
>        "final": true
>      }
>    ],
>    "result_index": 0
>  }
> ```

I have tried execute this substituting my STT service credentials, but I received error message instead of transcript result:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
An error occurred while processing your request.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;179&#46;24f01502&#46;1545478256&#46;101ee90d
</BODY></HTML>
```

I have tried different {path_to_file} variants - using slashes /, backslashes \ and  double backslashes \ \ but all of them returned the same error. What's wrong with my request or my STT service?

Comment: Do you keep the "@" at the start of your path? Have you tried to execute the curl command from the same directory the file is located?

Comment: Both answers: yes. I have tried this command:

curl -X POST -u "apikey:q25...JVC" --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary @audio-file.flac "https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"

and its variations with

@C:\UnityProjects\vr-speech-sandbox-vive-master\_Work\audio-file.flac

@C:/UnityProjects/vr-speech-sandbox-vive-master/_Work/audio-file.flac

@C:\\UnityProjects\\vr-speech-sandbox-vive-master\\_Work\\audio-file.flac

All these variants gave the same error.

Comment: Yana your `apikey` can be used to get an `access_token` and then call the service with that. Take a look at this page https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-iam.html#iam. It shows the process to do a Discovery API call but it's the same for Speech to Text

Comment: If you use one of the SDKs like Node.js or Python. then all this is done by the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of your service - this error occures when you mix up the service urls. For example creating the service in Frankfurt 
[image]

with this API URL `https://stream-fra.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize` and calling the service using the London location `gateway-lon`

```
curl -X POST \
-u "apikey:APIKEY" \
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac" \
--data-binary @audio-file.flac \
"https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
```

the error occures. It should probably return something like `{"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}`.

Comment: My service is registered for London, so it's ok with my URL.

Comment: Have you tried some other location? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No, I haven't tried other location. I'll try this. I have no proxy.